# Google analytics showing Paypal as transaction source

Tags: magento-1.8, magento-1.9, google-analytics

I have google analytics set up with my magento store and I have the ecommerce feature enabled.

However when a customer purchases a product using paypal. Google analytics shows that the traffic source of the sale was paypal. I am assuming this is because the customer is going off the website to complete the transaction using paypal then they come back to the site and see their order number on the success page. How can I fix this to show the real traffic source? A screenshot can be seen here http://screencast.com/t/4RGvMuME

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my opinion you would need to put paypal.com on the exclusion list and then it should work as usual again. I have had the same experience but this should be explained in the following links, just have a quick read through.

Link 1: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/analytics/vpEQwRHE-1w

Link 2: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2795830?hl=en&ref_topic=2790009

Hope that helps

Comment: Great! Thanks for the help. I dont have a high enough reputation to 1up the post.

Comment: I know that feeling :-)

Answer (score 5):

It is showing because your site is redirecting to your payment gateway page and after taking payment coming back to your site as a referral.

To resolve this issue you need to add your payment page domain (e.g. paypal.com) in Referral Exclusion List in Google Analytics.

Go to **Google Analytics -> Admin -> Property (select your site) -> Tracking Info -> Referral Exclusion List**

Hope it helps